# La imagen aparece en blanco al llamar a la función - Python, Tkinter, Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen, interfaz-gráfica, pillow

Necesito su ayuda en un pequeño programa que me plante como practica para seguir aprendiendo Python, hace poco que empecé en la programación y me gusto mucho.

Resumen: al ejecutar mi función, se coloca la imagen, pero no carga(aparece en blanco), no se ha que se debe el error, reviso el código(esta bien con la poca experiencia que tengo), tampoco la terminal me arroja ningún error.

Mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
import pyqrcode
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root=Tk()
root.geometry("520x400")
root.config(bg="#1b1b1b")
root.title("Qr Creator")

Var=StringVar()

#----Funciones------
def img():
    url=pyqrcode.create(Var.get())
    url.png("QR.gif", scale=5)
    photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.png")) #aqui debería de cargar la imagen
    l=Label(root,font="bold")
    l.config(image=photo)
    l.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=4)

#------Codigo--------

texto1=Label(root, text="URL: ", fg="white")
texto1.config(bg="#1b1b1b", font=("arial", 14))
texto1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)

box=Entry(root, textvariable=Var, width=40)
box.config(font=("arial", 14), fg="white", bg="#1b1b1b")
box.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

boton=Button(root, text="Create", fg="white", bg="#1b1b1b", command=img)
boton.config(font=("arial", 14))
boton.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=4)

boton=Button(root, text="update", fg="white", bg="#1b1b1b")
boton.config(font=("arial", 10))
boton.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=4)


root.mainloop()
```

Mi programa es un Generador de códigos QR, se que existen muchos online, pero quise hacer el mío, función que me falla es la `Img()` que es la encargada de colocar la imagen del código QR, en la interfaz, coloco la imagen sin ejecutar la función, y la imagen se ve bien, hice pruebas en otros proyectos, y la imagen si aparece al presionar el botón.

Les agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa la ruta de la imagen, parece ser que no la está encontrando.

Comment: La imagen la crea el mismo programa, he pensado que por ello da el error, pero así es que debe funcionar, el programa la crea en la misma carpeta, voy a intentar ponerlo el programa en una carpeta individual. Gracias :)